# Let A, B be two matrices, which satisfy Det(AB) $\neq$ Det(BA), prove rank(A) = rank(B) = 4

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R^{4 x5}}$ and $B$ $\in$ $\mathbb{R^{5 x4}}$ which satisfy det(A$\cdot$B) $\neq$ det(B$\cdot$A). Prove rank(A) = rank(B) = $4$.

So far I've tried separating the cases where one determinant is $0$, implying the other is not, then  the case where both are not equal to $0$, and tried working with some of the rank inequalities properties, but have gotten nowhere.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $$\det(BA) = 0,$$ we have $$\det(AB) \neq 0.$$
As such, $$rank(AB) = 4 \le \min(rank(A),rank(B)).$$

Comment: What if neither determinant is 0?

Comment: $BA$ must have determinant zero since it is a $5 \times 5$ matrix with rank at most $4$

Comment: Why is BA rank at most 4? is it because both rank(A) & rank(B) $\leq$ 4, and rank(BA) $\leq$ min(rank(A), rank(B))?

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $\text{rank}(AB)=\min(\text{rank}(A),\text{rank}(B))$.  Also, recall that the determinant of an invertible matrix is non-zero.  Those are the facts we need.

Suppose $\text{rank}(A)<4$ or $\text{rank}(B)<4$.  Then $\text{det}(AB)=0$ and $\text{det}(BA)=0$.  Therefore, the rank of $A$ and $B$ must both be 4.

If $\text{rank}(A)=4$ and $\text{rank}(B)=4$, then $\text{rank}(AB)=4$, and since $AB\in\mathbb{R}^{4\times 4}$, $AB$ is invertible.  Therefore, it has non-zero determinant.  But $BA\in\mathbb{R}^{5\times 5}$ also has rank $4$.  Therefore, it is non-invertible (Since the rank is less than the number of columns), which means its determinant is $0$.